# How to download ubuntu to harddisk?

Tags: usb, hard-drive

My USB ports are not working, cannot use DVD nor flash.
How to install ubuntu directly to HD?

Comment: Do you have any other machines you can use? Do you have any other external connectivity, like a firewire port?

Comment: From the internet

Comment: I think can try via network which is easy way to install directly in hdd.

Comment: You should at least give some more details about the system you have. What's installed on the system right now? How does it boot? if no DVD/CD/USB, does it have disk drive and could boot from a floppy? Please give some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far.  Sorry, more info: lenovo X60s, Win7, boots from hard disk, no flobby nor DVD in the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

To install Ubuntu without CD/DVD or USB pendrive, follow these steps:

Download Unetbootin from [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Run Unetbootin.

Now, from the drop-down menu under Type: select Hard Disk.

Next select the Diskimage. Browse to the directory where you downloaded the iso file of Ubuntu.

Press OK.

Next when you reboot, you will get a menu in that, select Unetbootin and you will get the "Try" or "Install" option there.

Finally, you can install your version of Ubuntu..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look for the ubuntu wiki https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

> Installation without a CD:
>
> Quick Install from USB - A quick guide to installing from a USB memory
>   stick. Intended for less technically-inclined readers.
>
> Install from USB - Installing from a USB memory stick (full version).
>
> USB stick + grub - Similar to above but using grub.
>
> Smart Boot Manager - Installing from a PC which will not boot from a
>   CD.
>
> Install within Windows - Yes, it is possible to install Ubuntu from
>   within Windows without using floppies, a CD, or any other removable
>   media! This uses Wubi, and installs Ubuntu as a large file that may be
>   uninstalled like any other program in Windows.
>
> Install with Floppies - Installing without a CD drive over a network.
>
> Install From Hard Drive with Floppies - Installing without a CD drive
>   or network capabilities from a hard drive.
>
> Install from Existing Linux - Installing using a spare partition from
>   an existing Linux system to house the Ubuntu CD image.
>
> Virtual Machine - Installing using a physical disk to a Virtual
>   Machine.
>
> Portable installed system booting from UEFI & BIOS - A system for a
>   USB pendrive - a good alternative to a persistent live system.